# Creating Video with OpenCV - Gstreamer codec not working

Tags: c++, opencv, video, gstreamer

I'm trying to write a video to disk using OpenCV. The code uses a video writer object to save the file in a .mpg format and with 30 frame/sec. I've specified the codec using the CV_FOURCC macro as follows:

```
VideoWriter put("test.mpg", CV_FOURCC('M','P','E','G'), 30, S);
```

when I execute the code I get the error:

```
userk@dopamine:~/Development/opencv-2.4.8/sketch/RegVideo$ ./vi
HIGHGUI ERROR: V4L/V4L2: VIDIOC_S_CROP
OpenCV Error: Unsupported format or combination of formats (Gstreamer Opencv backend doesn't support this codec acutally.) in CvVideoWriter_GStreamer::open, file /home/userk/Development/opencv-2.4.8/modules/highgui/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp, line 505
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /home/userk/Development/opencv-2.4.8/modules/highgui/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp:505: error: (-210) Gstreamer Opencv backend doesn't support this codec acutally. in function CvVideoWriter_GStreamer::open

Aborted (core dumped)
```

I've tried differents codecs such as MPEG-1, motion-jpeg, MPEG-4.2, MPEG-4.3, MPEG-4, H263, H263I and FLV1 but none of them worked. The problem seems to be V4L.

I've tried to install it with the following command, but I got errors after the make:

```
wget http://www.linuxtv.org/downloads/v4l-utils/v4l-utils-0.9.3.tar.bz2
tar xvf v4l-utils-0.9.3.tar.bz2
cd v4l-utils-0.9.3
make
sudo make install
```

This is the error message:

> make[3]: *** [qv4l2-moc_qv4l2.o] Error 1
>   make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/userk/Development/opencv-2.4.8/dependencies/v4l-utils-1.0.1/utils/qv4l2'
>   make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
>   make[2]: Leaving directory`/home/userk/Development/opencv-2.4.8/dependencies/v4l-utils-1.0.1/utils'
>   make[1]:**  [all-recursive] Error 1
>   make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/userk/Development/opencv-2.4.8/dependencies/v4l-utils-1.0.1'
>   make: ** [all] Error 2

What's wrong with v4l? Do you have any advice?